# Judging the naturalness of some sentences from a language-learning platform

Tags: usage

I'm looking at a language-learning platform that has hundreds of sentences translated into dozens of languages. I'm starting to suspect that some of the translations may not be very natural. When I set the source language to French, I got a few sentences that don't look quite right to me, including the following:

*L'étoile du rock a besoin d'un garde du corps pour la protéger des admirateurs fous*

*Je n'ai pas eu l'emploi en dépit d'être extrêmement qualifié*

It would be very helpful to know what the native speakers think of these sentences.

Comment: They look fine to me (maybe except "l'étoile du rock").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we do not use *étoile* to translate *star* into French, [apart maybe from Canadian French](http://www.doublage.qc.ca/p.php?i=162&idmovie=4992). As a native speaker from France, I would write it:

> *La star du rock a besoin d'un garde du corps pour la protéger des admirateurs fous.*

Someone who would really like to avoid the *anglicisme* would use synonyms, like **vedette**.

However, it's interesting to note that we do use the word *étoile* to translate *rising star* into *étoile montante*.

The second sentence looks perfectly fine to me.

The website that you're checking probably uses very literal (word-to-word) translations. In general, a good practice is to double-check with other translation websites, some of them driven by communities such as [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com).

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to Reyedi, I don't think that *Je n'ai pas eu l'emploi en dépit d'être extrêmement qualifié* sounds natural in French.  I wouldn't use *en dépit* de with an infinitive, I'd consider it as an anglicism.

To convey the same idea, you could say:

Je n'ai pas eu l'emploi alors que je suis extrêmement qualifié

or:

Je n'ai pas eu l'emploi et pourtant je suis extrêmement qualifié

Since I suspect the examples you're giving are machine-translated, I wonder if *admirateurs fous* isn't a translation of *crazy fans*, in which case, it'd possible to keep *fan* in French, but *fan fous* doesn't work, whereas *fans déchaînés* or *fans en folie* would be ok.

Comment: Many thanks. I don’t think they’re machine translated – the background is that I was trying the app to learn a third language and found it incredibly repetitive, so I set my source language (what the platform thinks is my native language) to German and French, just to try to make it more interesting. I can’t judge the naturalness of the German sentences but a couple of the French ones seemed slightly off, and if they are then the sentences in the language I’m trying to learn may well be too. The English sentences I saw were OK, but then I think they're the originals.

Comment: I can't upvote you for lack of reputation, unfortunately.